# Does not work validaton at second time

Tags: javascript, html, dom, event-handling

My code should switch color to red and back after click, but it works just one time!

```
<div class="time-block">00:00 - 00:59</div>
```

"red-my-day" class for switch color by add or remove him.

```
function addTimeBlocksHandler() {
    let arrTimeBlocks = document.getElementsByClassName("time-block");

    for (let i = 0; i < arrTimeBlocks.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("time-block")[i].classList.contains("red-my-day")) {
                arrTimeBlocks[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
                document.getElementsByClassName("time-block")[i].classList.remove("red-my-day");
            });
        } else if (!document.getElementsByClassName("time-block")[i].classList.contains("red-my-day")) {
            arrTimeBlocks[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
                document.getElementsByClassName("time-block")[i].classList.add("red-my-day");
            });
        }
    }


}

addTimeBlocksHandler();
```

Why this works one time, switch to red color and thats it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code do not work is when the javascript is executed it gets the class `class="time-block"` for the `div` element. Since this element do not have a class `red-my-day` it will skip the adding of `click` event listener inside the first `if` block and move to the `else` block and assign the listener for that event. That is why it was working only once for red color.

To simplify your code, you can just use `toggle()` so that it will toggle the class in each click on the element.

```js
function addTimeBlocksHandler() {
    let arrTimeBlocks = document.getElementsByClassName("time-block");
    for (let i = 0; i < arrTimeBlocks.length; i++) {
      arrTimeBlocks[i].addEventListener("click", (elem) => {
        elem.target.classList.toggle('red-my-day');
      });
    }
}

addTimeBlocksHandler();
```

```css
.red-my-day{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="time-block">00:00 - 00:59</div>
<div class="time-block">00:10 - 01:59</div>
<div class="time-block">00:20 - 02:59</div>
```